# После установки pip install pytelegrambotapi появилось AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'

Tags: python, termux

После установки pip install pytelegrambotapi появилось новая проблема
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'.

````
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.Telebot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardmarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Ҷустуҷуи дуст')
markup.add(item1)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Салом {0.first_name}! ХУШ ОМАДЕД БА БОТИ МО'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def bot_message(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(none_stop = True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Класс Telebot пишется "TeleBot"

[GitHub class TeleBot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/e64c06b7bc5fd8541eaf8f22202353f4af64f744/telebot/__init__.py#L83)